# How can I ignore everything except a specified environment?

Tags: packages, environments

In other words, I'd like to have the `comment` environment of the `verbatim` package "inverted".  I am pretty sure I read about some package allowing this some time ago, but I can't recall its name (nor can I Google it), and I don't want to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Also note: there is also the `comment` package which allows you to define your own comment environments and enable or disable them.

Comment: I know that, but still this is not what I want.  But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so I found it myself.  It is the `xcomment` package.  (From a glance at the code I suppose that it's an old, LaTeX 2.09 style file, but it seems to work fine with LaTeX2e.)

Comment: A small code example would be great.

Answer (score 3):

The `preview` package provides a `preview` environment and when active (`active` option) only displays the content in such environments. However, every environment is placed on its a page of its own, which might not what you want.