# Compile just a part of the contents in a .tex file

Tags: environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I ignore everything *except* a specified environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18616/how-can-i-ignore-everything-except-a-specified-environment)

I am looking for a package or a command, say `compileonly`, that can do the following task:

For a `.tex` file as following,

```
\begin{document}

This is A.

\begin{compileonly}
This is B
\end{compileonly}

This is C

\end{document}
```

The result will be `This is B`.

Does such a thing exist?

---

Thanks all the reply. Finally, the best solution is to use `xcomment` package and define a new environment `\compileconly` and use `\begin{compileonly}` and `\end{compileonly}` inside `\begin{xcomment}{compileonly}` and `\end{xcomment}`

Comment: Consider the [`comment` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment).

Comment: It seems that what I need is the complement of this package, since if one uses this package, one needs to comment out several places to just compile a part.

Comment: It is possible to do this using separate files with `\include` and `\includeonly`. Is this an option?

Comment: I don't prefer to do so. In fact, I am using Gummi to have a real-time preview. But if the .tex file gets bigger, then it would be slow. So I would like to have an easy way to comment out anything but only one place ( small section, for example).

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/commenting-out-large-sections, which seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this: [How can I ignore everything except a specified environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18616/how-can-i-ignore-everything-except-a-specified-environment)
(I don't know how to mark this question as a possible duplicate; also, I'd prefer the OP to confirm that.)

Answer (score 3):

```
\begin{document}
\iffalse    
This is A.

\else
This is B
\fi

\iffalse
This is C
\else
% nothing in this part
\fi
\end{document}
```

or

```
\begin{document}
\iffalse    
This is A.

\fi
This is B

\iffalse
This is C
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very similar to `comment` (yet much simpler).

Comment: The `comment` package is safer than an `\iffalse` solution. See the [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=conditional) for details.

Comment: and the possibility that one uses `\verb+\iftrue+` in his document is how big?? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using the `comment` package. It's not exactly as you would like, as it requires that you specify two environments: `dontcompile` and `compileonly`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{dontcompile}
\includecomment{compileonly}

\begin{document}

\begin{dontcompile}
This is A.
\end{dontcompile}

\begin{compileonly}
This is B
\end{compileonly}

% will always be compiled as it's not within dontcompile or compileonly
This is C

\end{document}
```

The `\includecomment` and `\excludecomment` can be toggled back and forth.

An alternative to this approach is to break your document into multiple files, and then `\include` them, as mentioned in the comments, and described on this post:

[Skip compilation of parts of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30292/skip-compilation-of-parts-of-a-document)

and the links within.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to specify a comment environment that starts from `\begin{document}` and ends at `\begin{compileonly}`. Unfortunately, AFAIK, none of the LaTeX comment packages allow you to specify the end marker.

In ConTeXt, you can use `buffers` to easily achieve the desired result. For example:

```
\def\starttext
    {\dostartbuffer[ignore][starttext][startcompileonly]}

\def\startcompileonly{\ctxcommand{starttext()}}
\def\stopcomileonly  {\ctxcommand{stoptext()}}
```

Using this the following test file works as expected.

```
\starttext

Text to be ignore
\iffalse
\undefined

\startcompileonly
Only compile this
\stopcomileonly

Text to be ignore
\iffalse
\undefined

\stoptext
```